# Is there a better way to formulate this constraint?

Tags: constraint, binary-variable

Let $x_{r}^{j}=1\iff$ the machine schedules job $j$ using resource $r$. My constraint says that: a resource cannot be used twice, i.e., if $x_{r}^{j}=1$, then $x_{r}^{j'}=0$ for $j'\neq j$. I write this as: $$x_{r}^{j}+x_{r}^{j'}\leq1,\forall j\neq j', \forall r.$$

Is there a better way to formulate this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can strengthen your "conflict" constraint to a "clique" constraint:
$$\sum_j x_r^j \le 1$$ for all $r$.
There are fewer of these, and they dominate the conflict constraints.

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the answer that was given before yours? I am asking because I can't see any difference in the both approaches. Am I missing something?

Comment: They were entered simultaneously.

Answer (score 9):

Same idea, but typically formulated as
$$\sum_j x_r^j \leq 1, \: \forall r$$
For binary $x$

Answer (score 4):

That seems like the right way to formulate it. There are lots of problems that use that sort of approach to ensure that at most one of two binary variables equal 1.

Comment: RobPratt's and @JBL's approach is better than mine. :)

Comment: Those approaches dominate algebraically, but they also result in denser constraint matrices (albeit with fewer rows), so I'm not sure it's a lock that they are always preferable.